# Your JAVA_HOME is invalid

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cordova, apache-cordova

He mirado todas las respuestas a esta solucion en este foro y en los habidos y por haber y no he conseguido que funcione de ninguna forma ya mi ultima solucion es preguntar aqui directamente si saben que puede pasar para que no funcione

[image: ERROR]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta ultima imagen es la variable PATH

Comment: Primero,  agreg a al PATH c:\program files\java\jdk1.8_291\bin. Luego cargas el powershell  y ejecutas java -version. Si  funciona vuelve a ejecutar el proceso quizá el error del JAVA_HOME es consecuencia de lo anterior.

Comment: Sii funciono muchas gracias llevaba ya varios dias en el trabajo incluso buscando y no salia nada

Answer (score 0):

mira, esto puede ser debido a dos cosas, primera que esta mal escrito, segunda que tu versión de Java no funciona o que instalaste varias versiones y en ese caso te recomiendo cambiar la versión, si tienes un Java 1.8 cámbialo a otra versión de esa misma, 1.8, a mi me paso con React Native, supongo que es lo que estas haciendo y te esta sucediendo, pruebalo. Te dejo algunas imágenes de mis variables de entorno[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias pero esto ya lo he probado por que lo vi en varios tutoriales de internet pero me seguia dando el mismo error

Comment: Tal vez necesitas solamente reiniciar la computadora, es necesario siempre que se hace, aunque no se, supongo lo habrás hecho también